# Why is there a loop in the ROC curve?

Tags: classification, algorithms, roc

I am trying to implement a multi-criteria classifier algorithm. It uses 6 criteria that output 1 or 0 if a specific signal is detected in the input data or not.

Then it computes a weighted average of these criteria and compares it with a threshold value. If is greater than the threshold, it outputs 1; otherwise, it outputs 0.

The weights are:

```
[0.04761905, 0.0952381 , 0.14285714, 0.19047619, 0.28571429, 0.23809524]
```

The problem is that the ROC curve for the algorithm contains a loop, which, as my understanding goes, should not appear in a ROC plot. As far as I know, a ROC curve increases monotonically.

[image]

The image shows the ROC curves for each criterion (1 to 6) and for the algorithm described (7).

For generating the plots, I calculate the results from all criteria (confusion matrix => TPR and FPR) for each ROC point corresponding to a threshold value, using all data sets. After changing the threshold value, I repeat the calculations, until the desired number of ROC points is reached.

If it has any significance, I mention that the threshold ranges of the criteria are different (e.g., 0-100, 0-1 or 0-20), but they are iterated in proportionally equal steps (e.g., if 10 ROC points are calculated, then the iteration steps are 100/10, 1/10 or 20/10). Also, I use an unequal number of data sets for the two cases (signal present, signal absent).

**Why is the loop appearing in the plot? Am I misunderstanding how to properly implement this multi-criteria algorithm? Am I calculating the ROC curve incorrectly?**

Comment: You're right that a ROC curve is monotonic, but a typical ROC curve is constructed using a much simpler procedure that doesn't seem closely related to what you present here. Where did you find this procedure? Does it have a name? Can you edit your post to include an article explaining how this procedure works?

Comment: If the "loop" you refer to is the non-monotonicity of the dashed line, that looks to me like a bug in the graphing code.  That suggests you should offer more details of how you computed and plotted the points in your plot.

Comment: @Sycorax I found and corrected the problem and the plot is OK now. Basically, I have a classifier algorithm (based on 6 criteria) and for calculating the ROC curve I determine the TPR and FPR (using all data sets available) corresponding to each decision threshold value (ROC point). So for, e.g. 10 ROC points, I run the algorithm 10 times on all data sets to get the TPR and FPR. This is my understanding on how the ROC curve is generated. Please tell me if you know a simpler/more efficient procedure.

Comment: If this question was based on an idiosyncratic error, then it sounds like deletion may be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By mistake, when calculating the ROC values for the algorithms I forgot to change the threshold. Instead, I was calculating using a fixed threshold and taking into account the variable thresholds of the 6 criteria.